# "Null check operator used on a Null Value" in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm considerably new to Flutter and I'm developing a Chat App using Firebase. I'm facing this "Null Check operator used on a Null Value" whenever I run the app. This is the error:

```
    ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building SignIn(dirty, state: _SignInState#ccbd1):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SignIn file:///D:/Android/chat_app/lib/helper/authenticate.dart:24:14
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _SignInState.signIn (package:chat_app/views/signin.dart:32:29)
#1      _SignInState.build (package:chat_app/views/signin.dart:98:28)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
...
====================================================================================================
```

This is **SignIn.dart**:

```
    import 'package:chatapp/helper/helperfunctions.dart';
import 'package:chatapp/helper/theme.dart';
import 'package:chatapp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:chatapp/services/database.dart';
import 'package:chatapp/views/chatrooms.dart';
import 'package:chatapp/views/forgot_password.dart';
import 'package:chatapp/widget/widget.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;

  SignIn(this.toggleView);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  TextEditingController emailEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  AuthService authService = new AuthService();

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool isLoading = false;

  signIn() async {
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      await authService
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              emailEditingController.text, passwordEditingController.text)
          .then((result) async {
        if (result != null)  {
          QuerySnapshot userInfoSnapshot =
              await DatabaseMethods().getUserInfo(emailEditingController.text);

          HelperFunctions.saveUserLoggedInSharedPreference(true);
          HelperFunctions.saveUserNameSharedPreference(
              userInfoSnapshot.documents[0].data["userName"]);
          HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(
              userInfoSnapshot.documents[0].data["userEmail"]);

          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatRoom()));
        } else {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
            //show snackbar
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarMain(context),
      body: isLoading
          ? Container(
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
          : Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Spacer(),
                  Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) {
                            return RegExp(
                                        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                                    .hasMatch(val)
                                ? null
                                : "Please Enter Correct Email";
                          },
                          controller: emailEditingController,
                          style: simpleTextStyle(),
                          decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("email"),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          validator: (val) {
                            return val.length > 6
                                ? null
                                : "Enter Password 6+ characters";
                          },
                          style: simpleTextStyle(),
                          controller: passwordEditingController,
                          decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("password"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ForgotPassword()));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              "Forgot Password?",
                              style: simpleTextStyle(),
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      signIn();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              const Color(0xff007EF4),
                              const Color(0xff2A75BC)
                            ],
                          )),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign In",
                        style: biggerTextStyle(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Text(
                      "Sign In with Google",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: CustomTheme.textColor),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Don't have account? ",
                        style: simpleTextStyle(),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          widget.toggleView();
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Register now",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Android Studio redirects me to this piece of code which is at 32:29 ->

```
 signIn() {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {

      HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(emailTextEditingController.text);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      databaseMethods.getUserByUserEmail(emailTextEditingController.text).then((val) {
        snapShotUserInfo = val;
        HelperFunctions
            .saveUserNameSharedPreference(snapShotUserInfo?.docs[0].data()["name"]);
      });

      
      authMethods.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailTextEditingController.text, passwordTextEditingController.text)
      .then((val) {
        if (val != null) {

          HelperFunctions.saveUserLoggedInSharedPreference(true);
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ChatRoom())
          );
        }
      });

    }
  }
```

Some help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you point out exact line of the error using debug tools.

Comment: The error keeps bringing me back to "if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {" and error pops up everywhere I call the "signIn()" method. So it has to be related to that..

Comment: Couldn't figure out the issue by looking at your code because its uses many external sources. one thing I  figure out is your flutter version or IDE is outdated. Latest IDE's and flutter will throw error on some of codes due to null safety. eg in textbox validation and form validattion

Comment: are you using vs code ?

Answer (score 0):

in signin define using

```
QuerySnapshot <dynamic>? snapshotUserInfo;
```

and use for null check

```
HelperFunctions
        .saveUserNameSharedPreference(snapshotUserInfo!.docs[0].data()["name"]);
```